# Jenkins push-to-deploy app engine failure

Tags: git, google-app-engine, jenkins

I am trying to configure push to deploy using google's official [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/push-to-deploy?hl=en). I am receiving field violations below, however, my app.yaml files appears to be formatted correctly.

```
ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Error Response: [400] Request contains an invalid argument.

Details: [
  [
    {
      "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
      "fieldViolations": [
        {
          "description": "Expression must start with \".\", \"/\", or \"(\" and may not be anchored.",
          "field": "version.handlers[0].url_regex"
        },
        {
          "description": "Expression must start with \".\", \"/\", or \"(\" and may not be anchored.",
          "field": "version.handlers[1].url_regex"
        },
        {
          "description": "Expression must start with \".\", \"/\", or \"(\" and may not be anchored.",
          "field": "version.handlers[2].url_regex"
        },
        {
          "description": "Expression must start with \".\", \"/\", or \"(\" and may not be anchored.",
          "field": "version.handlers[3].url_regex"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
]

Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE`
```

Here is my app.yaml

```
application: la-regia-site
version: default
runtime: php55
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /(.*\.(htm|html|css|js))$
  static_files: wordpress/\1
  upload: wordpress/.*\.(htm|html|css|js)$
  application_readable: true
  expiration: 7d

- url: /wp-content/(.*\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|woff|ttf|otf|eot|svg))$
  static_files: wordpress/wp-content/\1
  upload: wordpress/wp-content/.*\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|woff|ttf|otf|eot|svg)$
  application_readable: true
  expiration: 7d

- url: /(.*\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|woff|ttf|otf|eot|svg))$
  static_files: wordpress/\1
  upload: wordpress/.*\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|woff|ttf|otf|eot|svg)$
  application_readable: true
  expiration: 7d

- url: /wp-includes/images/media/(.*\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|woff|ttf|otf|eot|svg))$
  static_files: wordpress/wp-includes/images/media/\1
  upload: wordpress/wp-includes/images/media/.*\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|woff|ttf|otf|eot|svg)$
  application_readable: true
  expiration: 7d

- url: /wp-admin/(.+)
  script: wordpress/wp-admin/\1
  secure: always

- url: /wp-admin/
  script: wordpress/wp-admin/index.php
  secure: always

- url: /wp-login.php
  script: wordpress/wp-login.php
  secure: always

- url: /wp-cron.php
  script: wordpress/wp-cron.php
  login: admin

- url: /xmlrpc.php
  script: wordpress/xmlrpc.php

- url: /wp-(.+).php
  script: wordpress/wp-\1.php

- url: /(.+)?/?
  script: wordpress/index.php

skip_files:
- ^(.*/)?\.zip$
- ^(.*/)?\.bat$
- ^(.*/)?\.sh$
- ^(.*/)?\.md$
```

Anyone know what the issue could be?

Comment: Looks ok to me. Though weird that it's only complaining about the first four URLs. Maybe check for weird characters that have snuck in (e.g. invisible stuff like zero-width space, or non-breaking space, or whatever)?

Comment: What command produced that error output?

Comment: it doesn't like $ at the end for some reason. does anyone know why?